# iOS Xcode 5 Base internalization does nothing

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, xcode5

I'm trying to use Base internalization to localize my app. What I did - I made two .strings files for English and Russian version (Xcode did it for me), but when I change any string in MainStoryboard.strings(English), with the iPhone to English locale and launch app in debug mode nothing happens, all strings are still in Russian. What Im doing wrong ?

Comment: check the key that you given….

Comment: @Spynet what do you mean? I changed few values for different keys to be sure - still the same, no changes on runtime